# Boto3+Flask app, no errors but files will not upload to s3 bucket?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask, boto3

As the title says, I am running flask in order to upload files to an s3 bucket. All goes well, even to the point of an upload showing in the bottom corner of my browser, but nothing appears in my bucket!

App.py is as follows-

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import config as cfg
import boto3, os, time
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer

session = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='AKIA*********KQ', aws_secret_access_key='xtrtC***********BaYqv9f9q', region_name='us-west-2')
s3 = session.resource(service_name='s3')

AWS_BUCKET = ('flaskbucket')
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = False

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():

    uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("files[]")
    for upload_file in uploaded_files:
        if upload_file and allowed_file(upload_file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(str(time.time()) + upload_file.filename)

            dir_name = 'uploads/'
            if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
                os.makedirs(dir_name)

            file_path = os.path.join(dir_name, filename)

            app.logger.info("Saving file: %s", file_path)

            upload_file.save(file_path)
            transfer = S3Transfer(boto3.client(s3, cfg.AWS_REGION, aws_access_key_id=cfg.AWS_APP_ID,
                                               aws_secret_access_key=cfg.AWS_APP_SECRET))

            transfer.upload_file(file_path, AWS_BUCKET, file_path)

    return render_template('index.html')


def allowed_file(filename):
    return not (not ('.' in filename) or not (filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in cfg.ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS))

    @app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Authorization, Content-Type")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', "Authorization")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true")
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Max-Age', 60 * 60 * 24 * 20)
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

I get no errors when debugging, but when i use AWS to log the bucket I do get input from the flask app. I guess I'm just unsure of how to move forward without any indication of what is going wrong.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The AWS log files show me this-

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>13707ECF15B9DCE6</RequestId>
<HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: what do you mean "when I use aws to log the bucket"? What is the IAM policy on the access key you have hardcoded in to the script?

Comment: The user is my AWS root user, so no IAM policies there. I did this because I was told that 'POST' cannot be performed on a bucket without being the owner of the bucket. 

The bucket I am trying to access has this policy attached-

`{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Id": "Policy1449889578753",
 "Statement": [
  {
   "Sid": "Stmt1449889564405",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::7********6:root"
   },
   "Action": "s3:*",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::flaskbucket/*"
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: i'm so sorry I'm trying to get the hang of this formatting

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://0.0.0.0:5000/*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
    `
This is the CORS config for the bucket as well-

Comment: @tedder42 

I'm the worst, I'm sorry!

Comment: I think file_path string formatting is not right, try `app.logger.info("Saving file: %s") % file_path`

Comment: Not working yet;

<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">

inserts itself into my CORS file after i try to run it, if that helps at all